# ¿Cómo recorrer un array de java entre dos posiciones?

Tags: java, array, bucle-for

Tengo que hacer un programa con:

- Un vector donde hay guardados precios de mercada de cada día de la semana (lunes a sábado) de un producto. Por ejemplo: [9, 11, 8, 4, 7, 10].
- Se quiere calcular cuál es el mayor beneficio que puede obtener un comercial. En el caso anterior, el resultado es 6, ya que se compra un día 4 y se vende a 10. Sólo se puede comprar y vender en la misma semana.
- También se tiene que indicar el día en que se compra y se vende para obtener dicho beneficio.
- Otros ejemplos:

  [13, 7, 4, 8, 7, 6] devuelve 4
  [4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 6] devuelve 5
  [5, 7, 9, 8, 7, 10] devuelve 5

De momento, tengo el siguiente código, pero no sé cómo hacer para que empiece a contar el máximo a partir del valor mínimo, y sin empezar de nuevo la semana. Con el código siguiente el ejemplo , da la vuelta y me devuelve que el día para vender es el lunes (13) y debería darme el jueves (8) porque no puede dar la vuelta al vector.

```
public class comer{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] vect1 = {13,7,4,8,7,6};

        int i, j, iMenor, iMayor, iPosicion, jPosicion, Beneficio, nlongitud;

        iMenor=iMayor=vect1[0];
        iPosicion=0;
        jPosicion=0;
        Beneficio=0;
        nlongitud=0;

        for(i = 0; i < vect1.length; i++)
        {
            if(vect1[i]<iMenor)
            {
                iMenor=vect1[i];
                iPosicion = i;
                nlongitud = 5-iPosicion;
            }
        }

        for (j=iPosicion; j<nlongitud; j++)
        {
            if(vect1[j]>iMayor)
            {
                iMayor=vect1[j];
                jPosicion = j;

            }
        }

        Beneficio = iMayor - iMenor;


        System.out.println("Se compró por: " +  iMenor + " el día: " + iPosicion);
        System.out.println("Se vendió por: " +  iMayor + " el día: " + jPosicion);
        System.out.println("Por lo tanto, se obtuvo un beneficio de: "+ Beneficio + ". Comprando el día " + iPosicion + " y vendiendo el día " + jPosicion);
        System.out.println("la" + nlongitud);
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado por el momento?

Comment: He hecho:

iPosicion=5;
nlongitud=20-10

for (j=iPosicion;j<nlongitud;j++){
...

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que edites la pregunta e incluyas el código con el formato adecuado que has intentado, para que de esta forma podamos ver en qué fallas y poder ayudarte

Comment: Lo adecuado sería que si quieres que ambas posiciones sean índices, sin restas, que cambies el operador de la condición por `<=` o bien, le sumes 1 al último índice. Sobre encontrar el mayor, sería cosa de usar una variable de apoyo que almacene el valor más grande encontrado hasta el momento y lo vayas actualizando si encuentras otro más grande que ese.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La respuesta que buscas es un for bastante sencillo que inicie, en el indice mas bajo y busque el numero mas alto hasta el indice mas alto de la siguiente manera.

(Utilizare el caso del ejemplo, es decir entre el indice 5 y 10)

```
int[] array={13,10,2,5,6,4,7,8,15,20,5,2,8,9,10,5,5,4,58,5};

int indiceInicio=5,indicefinal=10;

int numeroMasAlto=array[indiceInicio];

for(int i=indiceInicio+1;i<=indicefinal;i++){
 if(array[i]>numeroMasAlto){
  numeroMasAlto=array[i];
 }
}
```

Al culminar el for, el numero mas alto estara almacenado en la variable numeroMasAlto

Comment: La comunidad no suele responder a preguntas, cuando el OP no incluye el código que tenga hecho hasta ahora. Ya que eso denota el esfuerzo y dedicación a la comunidad.

Comment: Ok, lo tomate en cuenta para futuras preguntas, gracias